# How to delete the Moodle backup file from the database and the file system?

Tags: moodle

To create backup files in Moodle by custom code I am using:

```
$bc = new backup_controller($type, $id, backup::FORMAT_MOODLE, backup::INTERACTIVE_YES, $backupmode, $userid, backup::RELEASESESSION_YES);

$backupid = $bc->get_backupid();

$backup = new backup_ui($bc);

// ...

// create filename, e.g. "backup-moodle2-course-35-map_2466-20211227-0925.mbz"
$filename = backup_plan_dbops::get_default_backup_filename($format, $type, $id, $users, $anonymised);

$bc->get_plan()->get_setting('filename')->set_value($filename);

$bc->finish_ui();

$bc->execute_plan();

$results = $bc->get_results();

$file = $results['backup_destination'];

echo $file->get_content();
                
$file->delete();

$backup->destroy();
```

It creates a MBZ file, it works fine.

However, I noticed that the backup files are piling up on the server (folder `/moodledata/filedir/`) and are **not deleted**. Using several Gigabyte of data.

I have tried to find out how to delete the backup from the Database **and** from the file system, but there is no official documentation/solution.

How to delete the created Moodle backup file from the database and the file system?

What I have tried without success:

```
// CLEAN UP
// delete_course() will trigger the course_deleted event and the course_content_deleted
// see source in "moodlelib.php"
delete_course($course->id, false);

// REMOVE left over backups (were contextid == 3 in "mdl_files")
$contextid = 3;

// instance to file storage
$fs = get_file_storage();

// delete all course backup files (adds them to "tool_recyclebin" in table "mdl_files")
$fs->delete_area_files($contextid, 'backup');

// delete recycle element
$fs->delete_area_files($contextid, 'tool_recyclebin', 'recyclebin_coursecat');

// optional clear Moodle caches
purge_all_caches();
```

And this one without success:

```
// memo: "If you remove a row in mdl_files that pointed to a file 
// you must also find that file via contenthash sluething and remove 
// the file @ moodledata/filedir/xx/xx/contenthashname."

// instance to file storage
$fs = get_file_storage();

// delete all course backup files (adds them to "tool_recyclebin" in table "mdl_files")
$fs->delete_area_files($contextid, 'backup');

// delete recycle element
$fs->delete_area_files($contextid, 'tool_recyclebin', 'recyclebin_coursecat');

// should empty folders \filedir and \trashdir
```

The Moodle backup folders are still not empty.